# Understanding of the topology of pointwise convergence

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

> Let $X$ be a set, $Y$ be a topological space, and $F$ be a set of functions from $X$ into $Y$. The weak topology on $X$ induced by $F$ is defined as the smallest topology $T$ on $X$ for which each function $f\in F$ is continuous. Show that convergence of nets in this topology is completely characterized by 
>   $$
> \lim_{\alpha\in A}x_\alpha=x
> $$
>   iff
>   $$
> \lim_{\alpha\in A}f(x_\alpha)=f(x)
> $$
>   for every $f\in F$.

---

By using the fact that $T$ is generated by  $\mathscr{B}:=\{f^{-1}(U)\mid f\in F,\ U\ \hbox{open in}\ Y \}$, I can show that one direction is true, namely, if $\lim_{\alpha\in A}x_\alpha=x$, then
$$
\lim_{x\in A}f(x_\alpha)=f(x)
$$
for every $f\in F$. Could anyone give me some ideas about the other direction? I tried to assume a non-convergent net in $X$, but I don't see get some $f\in F$ such that the corresponding net does not converge in $Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re on the right track. I’ll push you a bit further.

Suppose that $\langle f(x_\alpha):\alpha\in A\rangle$ converges to $f(x)$ for each $f\in F$, but $\langle x_\alpha:\alpha\in A\rangle$ does not converge to $x$. Then there must be an open nbhd $U$ of $x$ such that for each $\alpha\in A$ there is a $\beta(\alpha)\in A$ such that $\alpha\preceq\beta(\alpha)$ and $x_{\beta(\alpha)}\notin U$. (Here $\preceq$ is the order on the directed set $A$.)

By the definition of $T$ there must be $f_1,\ldots,f_n\in F$ and for $k=1,\ldots,n$ open nbhds $V_k$ of $f_k(x)$ in $Y$ such that

$$x\in\bigcap_{k=1}^nf_k^{-1}[V_k]\subseteq U\;.$$

Thus, for each $\alpha\in A$ we have $x_{\beta(\alpha)}\notin\bigcap_{k=1}^nf_k^{-1}[V_k]$.

By hypothesis $\langle f_k(x_\alpha):\alpha\in A\rangle$ converges to $f_k(x)$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$, so for $k=1,\ldots,n$ there is an $\alpha_k\in A$ such that $f_k(x_\alpha)\in V_k$ whenever $\alpha_k\preceq\alpha$. $A$ is directed, so there is an $\alpha_0\in A$ such that $\alpha_k\preceq\alpha_0$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$. Now consider $x_{\beta(\alpha_0)}$.

Comment: In the second paragraph, do you assume also that $x\in U$?

Comment: I don't follow the argument that "By the definition of $T$ there must be ... $x\in\cap_{k=1}^nf_k^{-1}[V_k]\subset U$". I guess just one of those $f_k$'s would be enough?

Comment: @Jack: You're right about $U$; I've fixed the wording to make that clearly. The sets of the form $f^{-1}[V]$ with $f\in F$ and $V$ open in $Y$ needn't be a base for any topology on $X$, but they are a subbase for $T$, and the collection of finite intersections of them is therefore a base for $T$.

Comment: In the second paragraph, $f$ is arbitrary. What is the $f$ in the third paragraph: "... and open nbhds $V_1,…,V_n$ of $f(x)$ in $Y$ such that ..."?

Comment: @Jack: Sorry: I apparently missed the ping and only just noticed this. You’re right that there’s clearly something wrong; I’ll take a look at it later tonight.

Comment: @Jack: I figured out what happened to the previous version and corrected it.